# Is there a way to test a mysql insert or update prior to actually inserting or updating?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

My PHP/Mysql script works in stages:

```
Insert Customer info
  Get new customer's ID via mysqli_insert_id(blah)
Insert into ADDRESS using new customer's ID
Insert into PHONE using new customer's ID
Insert into CONTACTS using new customer's ID
```

My problem is: If something goes wrong with one of the latter insert statements, MYSQL stops and throws an error of course, but the initial Customer INSERT already fired and was successful. Now if we go back and correct the error in the inputs and try to do this all again, we will have multiple partial entries for this Customer.

So Question: Is there a way to test ALL the MySQL Inserts for errors and upon finding none, THEN go ahead and submit them all?

For Example:

```
Insert Customer info (check for would-be errors; don't actually insert)
  Get new customer's ID...
Insert into ADDRESS...(check for would-be errors; don't actually insert)
Insert into PHONE...(check for would-be errors; don't actually insert)
Insert into CONTACTS...(check for would-be errors; don't actually insert)
```

OK, now that there were no errors thrown and nothing was actually inserted, do all the pre-screened inserts!

Does this exist?

Comment: Are you familiar with mysql transactions? Sounds like what you need: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MySQL transaction.

A transaction is a sequential group of database manipulation operations, which is performed as if it were one single work unit. In other words, a transaction will never be complete unless each individual operation within the group is successful. If any operation within the transaction fails, the entire transaction will fail.

Practically, you will club many SQL queries into a group and you will execute all of them together as part of a transaction.

Read this tutorial about [**MySQL transaction**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a transaction allows you to perform a series of queries, and *commit* all those changes at the end, or roll them back in case one of the queries failed.
If you're using PDO, the basic setup is this:

```
//optional
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare();
    $pdo->query();
    //in short, all your queries here
    $pdo->commit();//commit changes to DB
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $pdo->rollBack();//Nothing is changed in DB
}
```

Of course, transactions work best on *transaction-safe* storage engines (InnoDB, BerkeleyDB, ndbcluster). Since MySQL 5, transactions *do* work on MyISAM, but in order for them to be atomic, and thus safe to use, you'll have to lock and un-lock the table yourself.
See [the mysql docs for more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)

Comment: I think it must be noted that MyISAM tables don't support transactions; only InnoDB tables suport them.

Comment: @Barranka: Well, InnoDB, ndbcluster and most modern storage engines support transactions... I'll add a note on this, but I think most people should be aware that MyISAM is to be avoided 99% of the time anyway

Comment: hehehe Why that hatred against MyISAM? It's fast (*really fast*) and stable... it works... there are cases where MyISAM is the best choice. But if (for example) there's a need for transaction-support, I agree, it must not be used.

Comment: @Barranka: MyISAM is fundamentally flawed, it doesn't support Foreign Key constraints. This means data integrity is something you don't care about if you use MyISAM. The engine also doesn't lock on row level when inserting, but rather, it locks the table. So sure, for simple select queries, it _may_ be faster, but the moment you start inserting regularly, InnoDB beats it hands down. Seriously, update 1 field in 1 row and MyISAM blocks the entire table! Finally, InnoDB had one weakness: lacking full-text searching, but that's a feature that's been added to MySQL 5.5+ (though it needs some work)

Answer (score 0):

a transaction would be best for a roll back state. ifthats not possible prefix the statements with insert and it should let you know about any errors

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using mysqli to support my comment:

```
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['whatever']))
{

    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pw", "db");
    // begin transaction by setting autocommit to false;
    $con->autocommit(FALSE);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `something` (`data`) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['whatever']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt)
    {
        $con->rollback();
    }
    else
    {
        $con->commit();
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

You should know transactions require innodb tables. It helps to check the specs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

See barranka's comments for more details